# Copy same column from multiple worksheets to new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with about 20 sheets that has about 130 rows. What I'd like to do is copy column B from each worksheet and paste into either a new worksheet or a new workbook. Either is fine, I've tried both ways and I can seem to get the column B data from each worksheet to be in separate columns. 
I have tried the following code and it seems to loop through the sheets but it only retains column B from the last sheet. 
Is there a way to modify this code to paste each column B from each worksheet in a new column in the new sheet? I've tried other code snippets from posts here and none seem to do the final task.

```
Sub CopyColumns()

Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Destination As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Source In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Source.Name = "Master" Then
        MsgBox "Master sheet already exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

Set Destination = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets("summary"))
Destination.Name = "Master"

For Each Source In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets    
    If Source.Name <> "Master" And Source.Name <> "summary" Then        
        Last = Destination.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column        
        If Last = 1 Then
            Source.Range("B4:B129").Copy Destination.Columns(Last)
        Else
            Source.Range("B4:B129").Copy Destination.Columns(Last + 1)
        End If
    End If
Next Source
```

I have also tried the following to no avail

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set oldcol = ws.Range("B5:B129")
    Set newcol = Workbooks("OctTotals.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("B")
    oldcol.Copy Destination:=newcol
    oldcol.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    WorksheetFunction.Transpose (newcol.Value)
Next ws
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub CopyColumns()

    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Destination As Worksheet
    Dim rngDest As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each Source In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Source.Name = "Master" Then
            MsgBox "Master sheet already exist"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    Set Destination = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets("summary"))
    Destination.Name = "Master"
    Set rngDest = Destination.Range("A1") '<< for example: first paste location

    For Each Source In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets    
        If Source.Name <> "Master" And Source.Name <> "summary" Then

            Source.Range("B4:B129").Copy rngDest        
            Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(0, 1)  '<< next column over        

        End If
    Next Source

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Same Column From Multiple Worksheets to New Worksheet

- Copy the complete code into a standard module (e.g. `Module1`).
- Carefully adjust the values in the **const**ants section of the `Sub`.
- Only run the `Sub`. The `Function` is called by the `Sub`.
- If you need to place the `Target Worksheet` **before** another worksheet,
  change `wb.Worksheets.Add , wb.Worksheets(AfterSheetNameOrIndex)` to 
  `wb.Worksheets.Add wb.Worksheets(AfterSheetNameOrIndex)`.

**The Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Copies values of a specified column of each (with possible     '
'               exceptions) worksheet in a workbook to a newly created         '
'               worksheet in the same workbook.                                '
' Remarks:      If the worksheet to be created already exists, it will be      '
'               deleted. Then the result will be calculated and only now       '
'               the worksheet will be newly created to "recieve the data".     '
'               The Exceptions Array can be empty (""), or can contain one     '
'               worksheet name or a comma-separated list of worksheet names.   '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub copyColumns()
    On Error GoTo cleanError
    Const Proc As String = "CopyColumns"

    Const srcFirstRow As Long = 4
    Const srcCol As Variant = 2
    Const tgtName As String = "Master"
    Const tgtFirstCell As String = "A1"
    Const AfterSheetNameOrIndex As Variant = "Summary"
    Dim Exceptions As Variant
    Exceptions = Array("Summary")

    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    ' Delete possibly existing Target Worksheet.
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Worksheets(tgtName).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo cleanError

    ' Write values from each Source Worksheet to Sources Array of Arrays.
    Dim Sources As Variant: ReDim Sources(1 To wb.Worksheets.Count)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long, c As Long
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            c = c + 1
            Sources(c) = getColumnValues(ws, srcCol, srcFirstRow)
            If Not IsEmpty(Sources(c)) Then
                If UBound(Sources(c)) > r Then r = UBound(Sources(c))
                Debug.Print r, c, UBound(Sources(c)), "Not Empty"
            Else
                Debug.Print r, c, "Empty"
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    ReDim Preserve Sources(1 To c)

    ' Write values from Source Array of Arrays to Target Array.
    Dim Target As Variant: ReDim Target(1 To r, 1 To c)
    Dim j As Long, i As Long
    For j = 1 To c
        If Not IsEmpty(Sources(j)) Then
            For i = 1 To UBound(Sources(j))
                Target(i, j) = Sources(j)(i, 1)
            Next i
        End If
    Next j

    ' Write values from Target Array to Target Worksheet.
    wb.Worksheets.Add , wb.Worksheets(AfterSheetNameOrIndex)
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    ws.Name = tgtName
    ws.Range(tgtFirstCell).Resize(r, c) = Target

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation, "Success"

    Exit Sub

cleanError:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred in '" & Proc & "'." & vbCr _
         & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbCr & Err.Description, _
           vbCritical, Proc & " Error"
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the values of a non-empty one-column range starting     '
'               from a specified row, to a 2D one-based one-column array.      '
' Returns:      A 2D one-based one-column array.                               '
' Remarks:      If the column is empty or its last non-empty row is above      '
'               the specified row or if an error occurs the function will      '
'               return an empty variant. Therefore the function's result       '
'               can be tested with "IsEmpty".                                  '
'               If showMessages is set to true, a message box will be          '
'               displayed; so use it with caution.                             '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getColumnValues(Sheet As Worksheet, _
                         Optional ByVal AnyColumn As Variant = 1, _
                         Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 1, _
                         Optional ByVal showMessages As Boolean = False) _
        As Variant

    ' Prepare.
    Const Proc As String = "getColumnValues"
    If showMessages Then
        Dim msg As String
    End If
    On Error GoTo cleanError

    ' Define Column Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Columns(AnyColumn).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo EmptyColumnIssue
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then GoTo FirstRowIssue
    Set rng = Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(FirstRow, AnyColumn), rng)

    ' Write values from Column Range to Column Array.
    Dim Result As Variant
    If rng.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim Result(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Result(1, 1) = rng.Value
    Else
        Result = rng.Value
    End If
    getColumnValues = Result

    ' Possibly inform user.
    GoSub writeSuccess

    Exit Function

writeSuccess:
    If showMessages Then
        If UBound(Result) > 1 Then msg = "s"
        msg = "Range '" & rng.Address(0, 0) & "' " _
            & "was successfully written to the 2D one-based " _
            & "one-column array containing '" & UBound(Result) & "' " _
            & "element" & msg & " (row" & msg & ")."
        GoSub msgWSB
        MsgBox msg, vbInformation, Proc & ": Success"
    End If
    Return
EmptyColumnIssue:
    If showMessages Then
        msg = "Column '" & AnyColumn & "' is empty."
        GoSub msgWSB
        MsgBox msg, vbExclamation, Proc & ": Empty Column Issue"
    End If
    Exit Function
FirstRowIssue:
    If showMessages Then
        msg = "The last non-empty row '" & rng.Row & "' " _
            & "is smaller than the specified first row '" & FirstRow & "'."
        GoSub msgWSB
        MsgBox msg, vbExclamation, Proc & ": First Row Issue"
    End If
    Exit Function
msgWSB:
    msg = msg & vbCr & vbCr & "Worksheet: '" & Sheet.Name & "'" & vbCr _
            & "Workbook : '" & Sheet.Parent.Name & "'"
    Return
cleanError:
    If showMessages Then
        MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred in '" & Proc & "'." & vbCr _
             & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbCr & Err.Description _
               , vbCritical, Proc & " Error"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```